# C# ASP Load sequence forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms

I have a Windows application which has a browser in it. The Windows application opens a webpage in the browser. With this request it also sends form data (post method) to the webpage. Then, the webpage reads this post data and then the user is logged on.

The webpage that is being called is part of a web application that uses Forms Authentication. In my web.config I have:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="login" loginUrl="LogIn.aspx" defaultUrl="Manual.aspx"/>
</authentication>
```

So, if a page is requested and the user is not loggod on, the user will be redireced to login.aspx. Otherwise the user will be redirected to Manual.aspx.

My question is as follows: The Windows application calls the LogIn.aspx webpage. This page contains code that reads the post data, which is sent from the Windows Appllication. However, my post data in Login.aspx is empty. How come?

I know the post data is sent correctly from the Windows application. I know this because i made a complete new project with only 1 file. This file only read postdata and the results where as expected: the postdata is send from the Windows Application.

So my question. What is in this case the load sequence? Why can't login.aspx not read the postdata?

Comment: How does the "Windows Application" "send" the post-data?  Without such details, you're asking folks to take shots in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to check the actual requests that are being made? Is it possible that your web application is redirecting the user to the login page and thus clearing out the post data?